# How to scape special characters for linux, nodejs exec function

Tags: node.js, linux, ffmpeg, escaping, special-characters

I'm running this ffmpeg command on my linux server and while I paste it into the terminal, it works just fine but as soon as I use execPromise to run the EXACT same command, it returns an error.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const execPromise = promisify(exec);

const encode = async ffmpegCode => {
    try {
        console.log(ffmpegCode) //Here I can see that the code is the
                                //exact same one than the one that works
                                //when pasted into the terminal
        await execPromise(ffmpegCode);
        return 200
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

I need `\:` to be interpreted as such. When I type it as is, `\:`, the error message shows me that it interpreted it as `:` which is expected.

If I pass in `\\:`, I expect it to interpret it as I need it which would be `\:` but the error shows me that it interprets it as `\\:`.

`\\\:` is interpreted as `\\:` and `\\\\:` is interpreted as `\\\\:`.

Part of the command passed:

`...drawtext=text='timestamp \\: %{pts \\: localtime \\: 1665679092.241...`

Expected command:

`...drawtext=text='timestamp \: %{pts \: localtime \: 1665679092.241...`

Error message:

`...drawtext=text='timestamp \\: %{pts \\: localtime \\: 1665679092.241...`

How do I get `/:` through to the exec function?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, ChatGPT saved me by asking it the right questions.
It said that javascript was indeed escaping my `\` which is what was causing the problem. The answer was to use String.raw() which prevents this behavior.

`` const command = String.raw`...drawtext=text='timestamp \: %{pts \: localtime...` ``